# GoToStateAction refusing to change state

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, blend, visualstatemanager

I'm trying to make a little marker rectangle appear on the side of the following user control using a VisualStateManager, but my DataTrigger / EventTrigger (tried both) seem to refuse to change the UserControl's state. Any ideas? I'm currently using Blend for VS 2013 to design the control.

XAML:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Docular.Client.Windows.UI.SidebarElement"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" mc:Ignorable="d" 
         xmlns:dms="clr-namespace:Docular.Client.Windows.UI"
         xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
         xmlns:ei="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactions"
         Width="110" Height="110"
         DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
         x:Name="element" 
         Style="{DynamicResource SidebarElementStyle}">
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="SidebarElementStyle" TargetType="{x:Type UserControl}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type UserControl}">
                    <Grid x:Name="grid">
                        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                            <ei:DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsMouseOver, Mode=OneWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type dms:SidebarElement}}}" Value="True">
                                <ei:GoToStateAction x:Name="MouseOverAction" StateName="MouseOver" TargetObject="{Binding Mode=OneWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type dms:SidebarElement}}}"/>
                            </ei:DataTrigger>
                        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                    <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.25"/>
                                </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="Marker">
                                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0.75"/>
                                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextElement.Foreground)" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentLabel">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource MediumLightBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="Marker">
                                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1"/>
                                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextElement.Foreground)" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentLabel">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource BrightLightBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="5*"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="40*"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="15*"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="5*"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="5*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="25*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding CenterColumnWidth, Mode=OneWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="25*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="5*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                        <Rectangle x:Name="Marker"
                                   Fill="{DynamicResource HighlightBrush}"
                                   Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="2"
                                   Opacity="0"/>
                        <ContentControl x:Name="IconDisplay" 
                                        Content="{Binding Path=Icon, ElementName=element}" 
                                        Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1"/>
                        <Label x:Name="ContentLabel" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" 
                               Style="{DynamicResource LabelStyleRegularDarkLight}"
                               Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Grid.Row="2"/>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

Code-Behind:

```
public partial class SidebarElement : UserControl
{
    public static DependencyProperty CenterColumnWidthProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("CenterColumnWidth", typeof(GridLength), typeof(SidebarElement), new PropertyMetadata(new GridLength(40, GridUnitType.Star)));

    public static DependencyProperty IconProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Icon", typeof(Path), typeof(SidebarElement));

    [Bindable(true, BindingDirection.TwoWay)]
    public GridLength CenterColumnWidth
    {
        get
        {
            return (GridLength)(this.GetValue(CenterColumnWidthProperty) ?? default(GridLength));
        }
        set
        {
            this.SetValue(CenterColumnWidthProperty, value);
        }
    }

    [Bindable(true, BindingDirection.TwoWay)]
    public Path Icon
    {
        get
        {
            return (Path)this.GetValue(IconProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            this.SetValue(IconProperty, value);
        }
    }

    public SidebarElement()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

I'm not all-new to XAML but to me it seems like I still got a lot left to learn. ;)

Comment: You shouldnt need both a trigger and the `VisualState` to do what you're doing. One though I've ran into in the past though is Interpolation problems when using `Opacity` in a VSM as opposed to toggling `Visibility`, also using visibility is often suggested in most performance tips over opacity. So try ditching the trigger, and switch the effect to toggle visibility of that object instead of opacity.

Comment: @ChrisW. Triggering its visibility is not a direct option, or rather an option I'd like to avoid because I want a smooth fade-in and fade-out (which switching the visibility does not provide, IIRC) when the states change.
And I'm using the VSM instead of triggers directly because I want to avoid the trigger code-bloat and make use of it's automatic animation generation capabilities. And because of the lack of preconfigured `VisualState`s e.g. a `Button` defines, I need to trigger the state-change by hand using the triggers.

Comment: Ya that's where I'll correct you on a couple things, there's one of the beautiful things about using a VSM, you can use [VisualTransition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.visualtransition(v=vs.110).aspx) to accomplish your animation smoothly as you wish and more cleanly. As for the other part, I said to ditch the trigger and rely on the VSM by itself instead, as for lack of VisualStates, well thats void because you can specify just about whatever you want.

Comment: Don't I need to somehow give it the information when to go to which state though? Thanks for the other bit of information, though.

Comment: Oooh shoot, I owe an apology, I speed read right through this thing. No you're correct you'll need to specify it since it's not inherent in this case. So just change your DataTrigger to an EventTrigger for the MouseEnter event and do more like; `<ei:GoToStateAction TargetObject="{Binding ElementName=Yourelement}" StateName="MouseOver"/>` and you should be golden. Sorry again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wonderful, setting the TargetObject in the EventTrigger to `{Binding ElementName=grid}` fixed it!

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same problem with a Universal Application and simply setting the ElementName was not sufficient. Make sure that your Interactivity and your VisualStateManager tags are at the same hierarchical level. That fixed the problem in my case.